# Issue with UTF - 8 (cyrlic) encoding on fread

Tags: r, utf-8, data.table, fread

I am trying to read a standing csv file with the fread function. The issue is raised in this question - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939478/fread-data-table-in-r-with-specification-of-encoding) but its not quite the same problem.

My table contains variables with mixed fields filled in both latin and cyrlic letters.

When I try to load the file without any encoding I get unreadable text such as this one: Љђ‘’€ЌЉЂ ЊЂ

When I specify the encoding argument to:

```
data <- fread("./Datasets/data.csv", encoding = 'UTF-8') #read data
```

The cyrlic values get the following values: 
   "U+0082  U+008B U+0080 U+0084 U+008E" in tags < >

Any clue?

Comment: There is no problem. Which client are you using? The client may display the Unicode values instead of the actual characters, eg if its locale doesn't match the character's. What does `Sys.getlocale()` return? RStudio for example, has such issues

Comment: Yeah, I'm using RStudio. sys.getlocale() returns: "LC_COLLATE=Macedonian (FYROM)_Macedonia (FYROM).1251;LC_CTYPE=Macedonian (FYROM)_Macedonia (FYROM).1251;LC_MONETARY=Macedonian (FYROM)_Macedonia (FYROM).1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Macedonian (FYROM)_Macedonia (FYROM).1251"

Comment: Is there a way to change it to show the actual characters?

Comment: Save one of the values to a variable, eg x. I'll bet that  `Encoding(x)` will return `UTF-8`

Comment: Yes, it returns UTF - 8. But this still doesn't change the fact that I can't work on the string values. When I write the data in csv it remains with this wierd symbols.

Comment: On the other hand, the data gets read properly when I use read_xlsx, but Its way slower.